# absolute movement using css3 transitions and translates

Tags: css, transform, transition

I know that when you set a new css translate you need to the pixels you want to move, ex: `50px,60px`. 
So that is a relative movement to those pixels: http://jsfiddle.net/8CECx/
The div's remain next to each-other

Is there a way to move absolutly? For example you can say "move to 30px 50px" and have 2 elements overlap?

Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I’m adding another answer, since the question changed.

I’m still not sure what you’re trying to achieve. If you just want the 1st div to move and overlap the 2nd, why animate the 2nd as well? Or if you want both to move, just the 1st one more, why give it the same translateX value?

Also, I don’t see why you need transforms at all for this. If you just need `translate()` and no other transform, chances are absolute or relative positioning probably works for you just as well (and has much better browser support)

Comment: Imagine having 100 elements on a page; inline-blocks, and wanting them to all go to the same coordinates. By hand that would take hours.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to do that with pure CSS. Your best bet is to make their position absolute before the transition through JS and then move them to the end place (letting CSS transitions take care of the steps in between).